# How to show $A^2e_i=-\frac{1}{2} R_A(\cdot, \cdot)e_i$ in Topping's Lectures on the Ricci flow

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, ricci-flow

When I read the 9.5 of Topping's Lectures on the Ricci flow, I have some problem.

Assume $W$ is a vector bundle over manifold $(M,g)$, and $A$ is connection on $W$. $\{e_1,...,e_l\}$ is a frame of $W_p$, and extend it to a local frame for $W$ by radial parallel translation using the connection $A$, then we have  $Ae_i=0 $, and
$$
A^2e_i=-\frac{1}{2} R_A(\cdot, \cdot)e_i   \tag{1}
$$
where $R_A$ is the curvature of the connection $A$.   I don't know how to get $(1)$. In my view, for any $v_a,v_b\in T_pM$
$$
R_A(v_a,v_b)e_k= A_a A_b e_k - A_b A_a e_k
$$
where $A_ae_k=A_{v_a}e_k$.  How it imply $(1)$  ?

**PS(2022-7-4):** I use the notation of chapter 4 of   S.S. Chern and W.H. Chen's 《微分几何讲义》.

Assume the connection matrix of $W$ is
$$
\omega=
\begin{pmatrix}
\omega_1^1 ,...\omega_1^l
\\
~~\\
\omega_1^l ,...\omega_l^l
\end{pmatrix}
$$
where $\omega_a^b=\Gamma_{ai}^b dx^i$. And the curvature matrix is $\Omega= d\omega -\omega\wedge \omega$, namely
$$
\Omega=
\begin{pmatrix}
d\Gamma_{ai}^b \wedge dx^i  - \omega_a^r\wedge \omega_r^b
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Therefore, the curvature operator is
$$
R_A(\cdot, \cdot) e_a
=
\begin{pmatrix}
d\Gamma_{ai}^b \wedge dx^i  - \omega_a^r\wedge \omega_r^b
\end{pmatrix} \otimes e_b
$$
where $e_a=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_a}$ is tangent vector. I use the definition
$$
e_1\wedge e_2 = e_1 \otimes e_2 - e_2 \otimes e_1
$$
Then, I have
$$
R_A(\cdot, \cdot) e_a =  
d\Gamma_{ai}^r\otimes dx^i \otimes e_r
- dx^i \otimes d\Gamma_{ai}^r\otimes e_r  \\
-\Gamma_{ai}^b \Gamma_{bj}^r dx^i\otimes dx^j\otimes e_r 
+\Gamma_{bi}^r \Gamma_{aj}^b dx^i\otimes dx^j\otimes e_r
\\
=\left(
\frac{\partial \Gamma_{aj}^r}{\partial x_i}
-\frac{\partial \Gamma_{ai}^r}{\partial x_j}
-\Gamma_{ai}^b\Gamma_{bj}^r
+\Gamma_{bi}^r\Gamma_{aj}^b
\right) dx^i\otimes dx^j \otimes e_r  
\tag{2}
$$
On the other hand, first, I have
$$
A e_a = \Gamma_{ai}^b dx^i\otimes e_b
$$
Then
$$
A^2 e_a = 
A(
\Gamma_{ai}^b dx^i \otimes e_b
)\\
=
d\Gamma_{ai}^b \otimes dx^i \otimes e_b 
-
\Gamma_{ai}^b  \Gamma_{cd}^i dx^c \otimes dx^d\otimes e_b 
+
\Gamma_{ai}^b \Gamma_{bk}^r dx^i \otimes dx^k \otimes e_r
\\
=\left(
\frac{\partial \Gamma_{aj}^r}{\partial x_i}
-\Gamma_{ak}^r\Gamma_{ij}^k
+\Gamma_{ai}^b\Gamma_{bj}^r
\right)dx^i\otimes dx^j \otimes e_r  
\tag{3}
$$
Then, I think I should use an analogue of Bianchi to get $(1)$ from $(2)$ and $(3)$. But now, I still don't know how to use a suitable Bianchi.

Besides, of course, if assume  local trivialization, (2) and (3) will become much simple.

**PS(2022-7-5):** If I use the geodesic normal coordinate at $p$, then (2) and (3) become
$$
R_A(\cdot, \cdot) e_a
=
\begin{pmatrix}
d\Gamma_{ai}^b \wedge dx^i  - \omega_a^r\wedge \omega_r^b
\end{pmatrix} \otimes e_b
$$
where $e_a=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_a}$ is tangent vector. I use the definition
$$
e_1\wedge e_2 = e_1 \otimes e_2 - e_2 \otimes e_1
$$
Then, I have
$$
R_A(\cdot, \cdot) e_a 
=  
\left(
\frac{\partial \Gamma_{aj}^r}{\partial x_i}
-\frac{\partial \Gamma_{ai}^r}{\partial x_j}
\right) dx^i\otimes dx^j \otimes e_r  
\tag{4}
$$
$$
A^2 e_a 
=
\frac{\partial \Gamma_{aj}^r}{\partial x_i}
dx^i\otimes dx^j \otimes e_r  
\tag{5}
$$
The power series expansion of the metric in the coordinate is
$$
h_{ij}(x) = \delta_{ij} -\frac{1}{3} R_{ikjl}(p) x^k x^l  + O(|x|^3)
\tag{6}
$$
where $x$ is in the geodesic normal coordinate of $p$, $h$ is the metric of $W$, and $R$ is cuvature of connection $A$. But I want to show (1) at $p$, seemly, it has nothing to the point $x$.

**PS(2022-7-10):** In fact, the next calculation is finished  in two or three days ago. Just since feeling boring, I  stopped.

First,  since $Ah=0$, we have
$$
\Gamma_{ij}^m = \frac{1}{2}h^{lm} (\partial_i h_{jl}+ \partial_j h_{li} - \partial_l h_{ij})
$$
Therefore, in the geodesic normal coordinate of $p$, we have
$$
\partial_k \Gamma_{ij}^m(p)
= 
\frac{1}{2}h^{lm} (\partial_k\partial_i h_{jl}+ \partial_k\partial_j h_{li} - \partial_k\partial_l h_{ij})|_{x=p}
$$
Using (6) to calculate $\partial_k\partial_i h_{jl} (p)$ and $h^{lm} =\delta^{lm}$,we have
$$
\partial_k \Gamma_{ij}^m(p) = -\frac{1}{3} (R_{mijk}(p) +R_{mjik}(p))
\tag{7}
$$
From (4),(5), we have
$$
R_A(\cdot, \cdot) e_a =R_{raij} dx^i \otimes dx^j \otimes e_r
\tag{8}
$$
$$
A^2e_a = \frac{1}{3}(R_{raij} - R_{rjai}) dx^i\otimes dx^j\otimes e_r
\tag{9}
$$
Obviously, they are not  sustaining the (1).  Besides, I am sure (7) is right, since before I calculated it , I found it in [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_coordinates). The possible error is the miscalculate of (8) and (9). But, in fact, I have done 5 or 6 times, and not  sustaining the (1). Therefore, I feel boring...

Comment: Your formula isn't quite right. $A_ae_k = A_{v_a}e_k$, where $v_a \in T_pM$ (and not $W_p$) and the formula for curvature should be $$R_A(v_a, v_b) = A_aA_be_k - A_bA_ae_k.$$

Comment: @Deane   You are right. I neglect.

Comment: Have you tried to do this using local coordinates, a local trivialization, and Christoffel symbols?

Comment: @Deane   I make some progress, though not solving the problem. Whether I am on the right way ?

Comment: You haven't used the fact that the coordinates are geodesic normal coordinates, as stated by Topping. Use the power series expansion of the metric in these coordinates. See, for example, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/816483/metric-tensors-and-its-taylor-expansion-in-normal-coordinates

Comment: @Deane  Thanks your help. But I fail to get you. The power series expansion of metic is about the point near the origin of geodesic normal coordinate. But the (1) is just at $p$. I can't get the   relation of them.   Could you detail talk it ?   Thanks.

Comment: The power series expansion of the metric at the origin allows you to compute the values of the Christoffel symbols and their derivatives at the origin in terms of the curvature. That will give you the answer.

Comment: @Deane  Thanks, although my calculation is not sustaining the (1), but I feel your way must be right.  Maybe,  I miscalculated some detail.  Thanks again.

Comment: There are two key observations: In geodesic normal coordinates, 1) There is a formula for $\frac{\partial\Gamma^i_{jk}}{\partial x^l}(p)$ in terms of the second order partial derivatives of $h_{ij}$. 2) You can compute the second order partial derivatives of $h_{ij}$ at $p$ by differentiating (6) twice and then setting $x = 0$.

Comment: @Deane  You are really so patient.   In fact, after read your hint at  July 5,  I finished the calculate I add today.  I feel it is on your way. In fact, I feel your way must be right. Just because my miscalculate, I fail to get the right result. But at that time, I really feel boring and want to deal the ODE-PDE compare principle, so, I stopped.

Comment: You raise a good point. Sometimes, you can't figure out a step in a proof. Although it's sometimes good to spend some time trying to figure it out, it is also sometimes better to assume it's correct and move forward. Often, when you look at it again later, the step becomes obvious.

Comment: @Deane  I agree with you.  In my native language, it is  踏破铁鞋无觅处，得来全不费工夫。I don't know how to translate it. And  I guess you know Chinese, since your profile image seeemly be a Chinese tripod.   Thanks again.